# Flutter Codemagic IOS signing failed

Tags: flutter, codemagic

Hello everyone I want to publish my application flutter on an appstore (individual account) in order to test it on a physical phone unfortunately I don't have a mac so I had to go through codemagic but the problem from the Installing dependencies task the process fails with the error:

Failed to fetch signing files from Apple Developer Portal: Request to Apple Developer Portal failed with result code 35 for action "createProvisioningProfile.action". There are no current IOS devices on this team matching the provided device IDs.

I really don't know where the problem comes from as it's the first time for me to develop on platforms. Thank you for helping me!

**Logs :**

```
== Fetch code signing files from Apple Developer Portal ==
Fetch Development signing files for bundle identifier "*********"
Initializing Apple Developer Portal session with *********@****.com
Using Apple Developer Portal team ********* (*******) to fetch signing files
Found App ID "********" for bundle identifier "******"
Found code signing certificate "Apple Development iOS Push Services: *******************"
Found code signing certificate "iOS Development: *********"


Build failed :||
Failed to fetch signing files from Apple Developer Portal:
Request to Apple Developer Portal failed with result code 35 for action "createProvisioningProfile.action".
There are no current IOS devices on this team matching the provided device IDs.
```

**CODE MAGIC CONFIG**

```
Build overview
Index:
11
Branch:
master's degree
Workflow:
Default Workflow
Started:
in an hour
Duration:
21s
Status:
failed
Current configuration
Flutter channel:
stable
Mode:
release
Xcode version:
11.1
Build for:
iOS
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved the problem you need to attach an iphone to your developer apple account to do this you need to register it at the address below:

https://developer.apple.com/account/resources/devices/list